# Connecting to a vpn inside a vm but not on the host

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I normally connect my PC to a VPN and then browse from within a VM for anonimity.

If I was the leave my host PC as is - connecting the the internet through the ISP with no vpn but connect to the vpn inside the VM.

Will the VM traffic remain anonymous? as it will travel through the host to get out to the web.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Your VM sees the host as (most likely) a NAT router - just like your broadband router, and all your ISP's routers.